# Companion object's class

Tags: scala, reflection, companion-object

How do i get the class that the companion object is representing? For Example:

```
val user = User("something")
val userClazz = user.getClass //returns somepackage.User
```

Now if i have a companion User object:

```
object User {
  def myClass = this.getClass //seems to return a different type of class somepackage.User$
}
```

My question is how do i get the "true" case classes class? I have an instance with reflection where this is causing me to get some strange "private" constructor while trying to use this.getClass inside of the companion object.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the class of `User` with `classOf[User]`. Every (singleton) `object` has its own class. Companion object `User` is not an instance of class `User`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can't obtain the companion class, because the companion class might or might not exist or be class-loaded. Other than reflection, there is no way to do this in the language.

The recommended way is to declare a method in the companion object that returns the class, e.g. `companionClass` - this can be mandated with an interface that the object is extending.

Answer (score 0):

Hate to answer my own question and i'd gladly mark someone else's the correct one if someone knows a better way but this is the hack i came up with for now and it seems to get me where i want to go.

```
val clazzName = this.getClass.getName
val clazz = Class.forName(clazzName.substring(0, clazzName.length - 1))
```

Comment: how about [getEnclosingClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnclosingClass()). does that help in a scala context?